# JNA: how to call native method with args like (int argc, char** argv)?

Tags: java, c++, c, jna, args

I have a C/C++ function with the following signature:

```
extern "C" int something(int argc, char** argv);
```

With what arguments do I call this in Java? (What is the equivalent argument types?)

```
public interface NativeCall extends Library {
    public int something(/* equivalent args? */);
}
```

Comment: you could theoretically treat `char** argv` as `char* argv[]` which can be treated as std::vector<std::string>, or basically a fixed size array of strings. Maybe this will help you clear it out a bit

Comment: Oh... Thanks for your answer! But i find solution [here](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/overview-summary.html): int argc, String[] argv

Comment: You can answer your own question to show others that you have found an answer. Comments are not answers.

Comment: Did String[] worked out for you? Because for me it's more like `public int something(int argc, Pointer argv, int ArgumentsNbr);`